# Меню внутри другого меню

Tags: меню, php, wordpress, плагин

Всем привет!

Проблема состоит в том, чтобы грамотно отобразить главное меню, внутри которого родные элементы, а также элементы суб меню. Думаю, есть решение этой задачки при помощи walker, ну или плагином.

Грубо говоря, `wp_nav_menu()` должно находиться внутри другого `wp_nav_menu()`. Не знаю, как это грамотно сделать.

**Цель разбить меню на множество под-меню в админке и собрать его на стpанице сайта.**

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением проблемки.

Заранее благодарен всем.

Пример меню:

```
- Главное меню (20 эл)
    1 название и линк
      1.1 name1,  source - sub menu1 (20 эл)
      1.2 name2,  source - sub menu2 (20 эл)
      1.3 name3,  source - sub menu3 (20 эл)
      1.4 name4,  source - sub menu4 (20 эл)
      1.5 name5,  source - sub menu5 (20 эл)
      1.6 name6,  source - sub menu6 (20 эл)
      1.7 name7,  source - sub menu7 (20 эл)
      1.8 name8,  source - sub menu8 (20 эл)
      1.9 name9,  source - sub menu9 (20 эл)
    2 Блог
    3 Страницы
      3.1 Pages ....
      3.10 Pages ....
```

Comment: @DanX, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Это не учебное, ввиду ограниченой функциональности WP построение меню внутри другого меню невозможно, стандартными встроенными инструментами. Вот и немогу внедрить задумку, разбить одно огромное меню на десяток суб-меню, тем самым облагородив свой вебсайт.

Comment: @DanX когда создаете меню в админке можно вкладывать один пункт в другой, так образуется вложенность, смотрите скрипт wp-admin/nav-menus.php, как там устроен вывод меню, думаю, разберетесь.

Comment: @zsiteru это правильно, но загвоздка в том, что меню станет громадным, т.е 400 вкладок. Это ужас как много. Поэтому цель разбить меню на под-меню в админке и собрать его на станице сайта.

Comment: @DanX тогда, скорее всего, Вам нужно переписывать

    Walker apply_filters( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit', $menu_id );

Мне кажется, даже если Вы найдете готовое решение, оно Вас не совсем устроит, так как такое маштабное меню редкость.

Comment: @zsiteru абсолютно солидарен, к сожалению, пока не нашел ни на наших и ни на англ. ресурсах даже намека на мою идею. Хотя разработчики могли легко встроить эту фишку в ядро ВП. Можно было включить выбор элементов уже созданных меню при создании новых меню.